# Specify Message Handler Ordering in NServiceBus 6.x

Tags: c#, .net, nservicebus

ISpecifyMessageHandlerOrdering interface is obsolete in NServiceBus 6.x.

Documentation tells to specify order by calling ExecuteTheseHandlersFirst method on endpointConfiguration.

I am upgrading NSB from 5.x to 6.x. In solution I have endpointConfiguration in one core library and many handlers in other libraries. Is there a way to specify handler ordering in these other libraries (5.x manner)?

Comment: So are you only doing a partial upgrade?

Comment: Nope. Whole solution - including core project and handler projects.

Comment: So are you asking if it will still work when specified in the obsolete way?

Comment: I want to upgrade to NSB 6.x, I want to save order in which handlers are executed and I don't want to specify it in configuration code (because I don't have references to handler libraries in core/configuration library)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, your problem comes from the fact that an `ISpecifyMessageHandlerOrdering` implementation could be placed anywhere and be picked up by assembly scanning, where the `EndpointConfiguration` is in a predefined spot, and *not* where your handlers are. Correct?

If that's the case, I think the [`INeedInitialization`](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/lifecycle/ineedinitialization) interface would be the right extension point for you. It gives you access to the `EndpointConfiguration` and is picked up by assembly scanning.

Alternatively, there's a community project called [NServiceBus.HandlerOrdering](https://github.com/SimonCropp/HandlerOrdering) that allows you to express handler orderings more expressively right on the handler, adding interfaces like `IWantToRunAfter<OtherHandler>`. Here's a [sample showing how that project works](https://docs.particular.net/samples/handler-ordering-by-interface/).

Comment: This is what I've been looking for. Thank you!